# Associate a Taxonomy term to user who creates it

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

I have field **Company Name** which is a term reference to a vocabulary with same name. when user types the field if name already exists, so auto complete showed that or else it will be added as taxonomy term. let us consider "**BBB**" is the company name he entered.

On next scenario when another user keying in this company name as "**BBB**" so its already their in the taxonomy so i have to send a mail to the user who created added the term "**BBB**" first.

I tried using rules module but i couldn't find way to get the user who created the term.Meanwhile i use Profile2 module so writing submit handler is best?

Answer (score 1):

You can **add a user [reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field** to the taxonomy entity so it will have a Name, Description and that User reference field.

Then you have to run a **Rule** on events "taxonomy_term_update" and "taxonomy_term_insert" that will save the user id on that field. See the rules code example [on a Drupal.org related issue](https://drupal.org/node/979946#comment-6750042).

Comment: What if you want to allow duplicates:

term AAA -> user1 ( only visible for user 1) term AAA -> user2 ( only visible for user 2 )